# Is it true that given any two point in $M$ if there exists an unique geodesic joining those two points, then $M \sim \mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

This following doubt initially came to my mind while thinking the relationship between number of genus of a manifold and number of geodesic between given two points.

**DOUBT:** Suppose $M\subset \mathbb{R^m}$ is a riemannian manifold with induced riemannian metric from $\mathbb{R^m}$. If given any two point $x,y\in M$ there exists a unique geodesic joining those two points. Then is it true that $M$ is diffeomorphic with $\mathbb{R^n}$ for some $n\leq m$??

Also it will be very helpful if someone can give me some reference from where I can read the relation between number of geodesics and number of genus.

Comment: How about a manifold of constant negative curvature? E.g. any hyperbolic plane. It cannot be imbedded as a whole but some bounded (closed or open) subset can be.

Answer (score 4):

The magic words are ["exponential map".](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry))

Comment: By the Nash embedding theorem, this question is actually equivalent to [http://mathoverflow.net/q/223323/70808]. Please see the comments to Raziel's answer - I don't think it is as trivial as your answer suggests. On the other hand, if you can prove that the exponential map is necessarily a local diffeo in this case, please explain a bit more.